# JSF h:selectOneMenu wont call relevant setter method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

Hi I've got a question

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cmbFileStatus1"  disabled="#{!schedulerController.oldFile}" 
    value="#{schedulerController.test}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Show All--" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{schedulerController.statusList}"/>
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="dataTable"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The above code the ajax executes(I checked through firebug). But the thing is the selected value wont be set to **h:selectOneMenu** value parameter.

There is a **h:form** tag that is wrapping this element, plus there are two other elements similarly using ajax as shown here. But they are positioned before this element in the DOM, they call the relevant setter methods and the updates the bean variables.

But this element it doesn't set necessary selected value.

Also another detail, the list that is populated for selection, it is a list created from enum values.

One instance I moved the problematic code to the top of the DOM (before the other two elements that ajax is applied) and then it hit the setter method when ran in debug mode.

I cannot understand whats wrong, it doesn't show any javascript errors and such. The JSF version is 2.0, this is an old project.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: How is this myfaces related? Does it work in Mojarra?

Comment: Please check your class is public or not.even if you have getter/setter.if your class is not public,it cannot call property of that class.

Comment: Read all bullets in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked and check if there is solution in there

Comment: Btw. `<f:selectItems` is missing `var=`, `itemLabel=` and `itemValue=`?